# load more in table view for iOS

Tags: ios, tableview

I need a good example to implementation a "pull up to load more" feature in table view.

I tried to use [DragRefreshAndLoadMore](https://github.com/OpenFibers/DragRefreshAndLoadMoreTableDemo) plugin

but the demo example is empty , and i didn't  know how to complete the code.

if some one know how to do it , or give me another good plugin , i will be thankful.

Comment: is my question unclear ?!! why guys dislike it ?!!

Answer (score 1):

Since iOS 6 there is a built-in class to do what you want:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIRefreshControl_class/Reference/Reference.html

Have you looked at this?

Comment: yes. but this is "pull down to refresh" feature, i don't need this, i want "pull up to load more" which be in the down of the table

Comment: Ok, sorry I overread.
I think your problem can be solved with a similar library though. Take a look at this: https://github.com/leah/PullToRefresh It shows you how to create one of the release to refresh views. Instead of refreshing you just change the code to add data to your tableView. Then you can use: insertRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation: (see Apple's UITableView Class reference)
Be careful copying code though, when it comes to licenses etc.